# SQL - Accessing results from COUNT (*) AS TOTAL in outer layers?

Tags: sql

Here is the question as it appears on the sheet: "Get website numbers for websites that have at least all of the products purchased by customer C100."

Ok, here is some code:

```
SELECT W.WEBSITEID
FROM WEBSITE AS W
WHERE W.WEBSITEID IN (

    SELECT COUNT (*) AS TOTAL
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT P.PNUM
               FROM PURCHASES AS P
               WHERE P.CNUM = 'C100')
AND TOTAL = 2

)
```

What I am trying to do is count the number of purchases ( (Count (*) ) for each P.WNum (or website number) that have a P.CNum (customer number) of the string 'C100'. The question wants to know all W.WebsiteID (website numbers) for websites that have at least all of the products purchased by customer 'C100'. Since customer 100 purchased two products according to the chart (not shown), I'm looking for all websites that have sold exactly two distinct products with a P.CNum of 'C100'.

Sorry, I realize this is convoluted, and my way probably isn't even the best way to solve the problem (different approaches are certainly welcome)

Down to the crux of the matter: when I try and run this, it asks for a value for TOTAL. Total is a result of the function Count (*) AS Total. How come I'm not able to access it? How do I check to make sure that the total is equal to 2 (the amount of distinct products purchased by 'C100'?

I really appreciate any and all help with this, I'm just a university student trying to make sense of this SQL assignment.

Any questions, feel free to let me know, I'll get back to you A.S.A.P.

Sample data: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfRnZ.jpg

Comment: Show sample data and desired output for a faster result.  Your language is not very clear.

Comment: I'll get you the sample data, give me a moment to find the pdf file. Here is the question as it appears on the sheet: "Get website numbers for websites that have at least all of the products purchased by customer C100.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/4tYBG

Comment: what is *"Get website numbers for websites that have at least all of the products purchased by customer C100."* means? especially *".. at least all.."*..

Comment: Hint: `GROUP BY` combined with `HAVING`.